# Re-entering the USA with an expired VWP

Tags: usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, eu

I have visited the USA and I have VWP to my passport now it is out of date, but my ESTA is still valid. Am I able to enter the USA again if my VWP is out of date but my ESTA is valid?

I am little bit curious because I was told by officer that the VWP needs to be taken out of my passport when leaving the USA for the very last time and the customs officer didn't do that, so I am little bit worried now. Sorry for my English though. I am from the EU.

Comment: Do you have a paper I-94 form stapled into your passport?  If so, how did you travel out of the US most recently (and how long ago was that)?

Comment: In addition to @phoog's questions, could you check your travel history [at the CBP I-94 web site](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/#/home) to see if your last departure is recorded?

Comment: I traveled by plane fron Detroit to amsterdam like two months ago